# Change Windows Form Panel Location at Runtime

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have designed a Form to use as a Template for printing. It is designed to fill the form, so I have to take into account the Page Margins before drawing them.

My current issue is trying to get the [System.Windows.Forms.Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel.aspx) controls to shift over by the amount specified by the [System.Drawing.Printing.Margins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.margins.aspx).

```
private static void MarginShift(Control ctrl, Margins m) {
  Label lbl = ctrl as Label;
  if (lbl != null) {
    lbl.Location = new Point(lbl.Location.X + m.Left, lbl.Location.Y + m.Top);
  } else {
    Panel pnl = ctrl as Panel;
    if (pnl != null) {
      int x = pnl.Location.X;
      int y = pnl.Location.Y;
      pnl.Location = new Point(x + m.Left, y + m.Top);
      if ((pnl.Location.X == x) && (pnl.Location.Y == y) &&
          ((0 < m.Left) || (0 < m.Top))) {
        Console.WriteLine("WTF?");
      }
      foreach (Control c2 in pnl.Controls) {
        MarginShift(c2, m);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My little Console output gets hit for every [Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel.aspx) that I pass from my Template Form.

Microsoft's documentation of the [Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel.aspx) control says this of the [Location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.location.aspx) value:

> Gets or sets the coordinates of the upper-left corner of the control relative to the upper-left corner of its container.

So, why does shifting a [Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel.aspx) using the [Margins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.margins.aspx) not move the [Location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.location.aspx)?

What do I need to do to correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind. Panels were docked to the form.